# Non-repeating permutations

Tags: c++, combinations, permutation

I am having an issue. I want to iterate through all the possible combinations of the 26 letters of the alphabet (Well.... only 25 letters, I want to exclude 'q'). It appears to be simple, but it is proving difficult. I want to start with a char* containing a-z excluding q, and a for loop which will flip through every possible combination of those letters (order matters, no repeating letters), executing a function that checks if that combination is the one I'm looking for.

std::next_permutation doesn't work for my scenario.
Specifically, I need code that will iterate backwards. Start with:
a    bcd.... z,
b    acde.... z,
c    abde.... z,
...
z    abcd.... y,

ab   cdef.... z,
ac   bdef.... z,
ad
..
az

ba
bc
bd

Pretty much come up with every combination of two letters words, then three letters, then four, adding the rest of the alphabet afterwords.
I have the code that adds the rest of the alphabet, so all I need is the first part.

After I figure out how to generate n-letter words, it will be causing repeats. Iterate through every two letter word and I get "ab ac ad ... az ba bc bd .. bz" but remember I add abcdef..z to the end of it (excluding used up letters) so it is actually "abcd..z acbde..z adbcef..z" etc. The two letter word ab and the three letter word abc overlap, which is inefficient for larger keywords.

Comment: In the future, please tag your questions with the language you're using.

Comment: k, thanks. I've never posted a question here before.

Comment: Do you really mean ALL possible permutations? That's 25! = 15511210043330985984000000 possibilities... is there a limit on the length of the permutation?

Comment: Yes, every single one, I know it's a lot of permutations. I was challenged by a friend to crack a Playfair's Cipher. I can run my computer over night if necessary.

Comment: @Nickpipitone lot of nights, I think...

Comment: Not necessarily. I used std::next_permutation and it iterated through the first 5 digits instantly, and the 6th digit was flipping by. So assuming the keyword is only 5 digits long, it'll be cracked instantaneously. If it was 6 or 7, in the matter of minutes. 8-12 will take at least an hour. More than that and then it'll take days.

Comment: With a search space of size 25!, even if you could generate one full permutation at every clock cycle on a 2 GHz CPU (that is, generating 2 billion permutations per second, which is overestimating it by quite a bit) it would take nearly 250 million years to produce the entire output. Let's hope the master race (I'm betting on cockroaches) on the planet at that time can understand our human alphabet and use the result.

Comment: @DenielKO But I don't need all 25! combinations, that's only assuming the key is zyxw...ba. If the key is only a few characters long, It'll be cracked almost instantly. I doubt the keyword is more than 6 characters long, which was iterated through within a minute when I tried std::next_permutation.

Comment: But you just said in a comment, "Yes, every single one". If you already know how to call next_permutation() to generate the permutations, what exactly is the question?

Comment: This sounds kinda trivial, unless you are not describing the constraints or requirements of the code, and you've also not provided an [sscce](http://sscce.org) so we've no idea what you've already discounted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, every single one must be iterated to crack every single Playfair Cipher that gets thrown at me. This will only happen if the key is zyxw..a. If it isn't that, I'll crack the code before that. next_permutation will take a VERY long time before hitting the key 'orangebcdf...z', so I want to iterate so that the left is iterated first, not the right (which is the way next_permutation does it).

Comment: Remember that in Playfair cipher I = J.

Comment: No, you can omit q instead of replacing i with j. I omitted 'q'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  I usually avoid recursion but here it works quite well :

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::find;

void printVec(vector<char> &vec)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << vec[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void incrementCharAvoidingDuplicates(vector<char> v, char &c)
{
    // increment newChar until we find one not in the vector already
    while(std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), c)!=v.end())
    {
        c++;
    }
}

bool incrementVec(vector<char> &v)
{
    if(v.size() == 0 || v.size() >= 25)
            return false;

    //try incrementing the final character
    char newChar = v.back() + 1;

    incrementCharAvoidingDuplicates(v, newChar);

    // if it's still in range, we have succesfully incremented the vector
    if(newChar <= 'z')
    {
        v.back() = newChar;

        return true;
    }
    // if not (e.g. "abz") then remove the final character and try to increment the base part instead
    else
    {
        vector<char> w(v.begin(), v.end() - 1);

        if(incrementVec(w))
        {
            // we succeeded in incrementing the base ... so find a remaining character that doesn't conflict and append it
            // (note there will always be one since we insisted size < 25)
            v.resize(w.size());
            std::copy(w.begin(), w.end(), v.begin());

            char newChar = 'a';

            incrementCharAvoidingDuplicates(v, newChar);

            v.push_back(newChar);

            return true;
        }
        // otherwise we could not increment the final char, could not increment the base...so we are done
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    static const char arr[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    vector<char> originalAlphabet (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );
    vector<char> currentWord;
    int desiredWordLength;

    for(desiredWordLength = 1; desiredWordLength < 25; desiredWordLength++)
    {
        currentWord.clear();

        //build first list e.g. a, abc, abcdef, ...
        for(int j = 0; j < desiredWordLength; j++)
        {
            currentWord.push_back(originalAlphabet[j]);
        }

        do{
            printVec(currentWord);
        } while( incrementVec(currentWord));

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note you could reuse the function incrementCharAvoidingDuplicates to fill in the remaining characters up to 25

Comment: I already figured it out, but thank you! :) I had 25 nested for loops so your idea seems better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the idea of backtracking to start with. But generating 25! is a daunting task. Iterating through such a large search space will take a lot (i really mean a lot) for a normal computer. 
You should try to PRUNE your search space by thinking of such cases which you are sure that it can never occur in the desired output.
You should look for a technique called backtracking with prunning.